# Добавление меню в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Я добавляю меню в WordPress. Сначала я его зарегистрировала с помощью `register_nav_menu()`, затем

```
wp_nav_menu (array ( 'theme_location' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => 'nav'));
```

выводит меню (подключила в файле `header.php`). Меню выводится, но некорректно отображается ("падает" под блок, в котором должно было быть). Как можно решить эту проблему?

Буду очень благодарна.

Comment: Вам сегодня дали ответы на два вопроса. От вас - никакой реакции. Вы в самом деле думаете, что люди всегда будут тратить на вас свое время?

Comment: Я еще новичок и давать кому-то неправильные ответы на вопросы не очень хорошо.

Comment: А вы давали кому-то ответы? )) Вижу, что после моего комментария вы прошлись по отвечающим и поблагодарили их. Это уже что-то. Но здесь многие "работают" для повышения баллов своей репутации. Поэтому, если ответ лично вам помог, стоит его отметить плюсиком (стрелка вверх) или как принятый (галочка). Кроме того, отмеченные ответы помогут сориентироваться другим посетителям, которые ищут ответа на вопрос, аналогичный вашему.

Comment: Я уже писала, что новичок и не хочу давать неправильные ответы. А отметить ответ плюсиком мне пока не позволяет моя репутация (надо иметь 15 баллов). Пока я могу только поблагодарить. Простите, что делаю что-то не так.

Comment: Так это не ответы, а оценки. А "принять" ответ (поставить галочку) вы можете всегда. Допустим вам ответили, вы применили это у себя, код сработал - примите ответ. И отвечающему будет приятно, и для других, кто через поиск сюда зайдет - полезно.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Я еще много всего не знаю, как все должно происходить. Но буду учиться делать правильно.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Будем стараться помочь с ответами. Что касается конкретно данного вопроса, то дело, скорее всего, в стилях. Можете показать итоговую верстку - html и css? Или дать ссылку на сайт?

Comment: Я благодарю всех тех кто мне помог.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я по поводу своего вопроса. Если я добавляю меню с помощью wp_nav_menu (), меню "падает".

Comment: Что касается конкретно данного вопроса, то дело, скорее всего, в стилях. Можете показать итоговую верстку - html и css? Или дать ссылку на сайт?

Comment: <!--<ul id="nav">
       <li><a href="">home</a></li>
       <li><a href="">About </a></li>
       <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>-->
 </div><!--end nav_wrapper-->
</div><!--end header-->

<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'  => 'menu', 'menu_id' => 'nav'));?>

Comment: из этого понять нельзя ничего. Надо видеть живой сайт или полную структуру готового html (из браузера) и css

Comment: Извините. Я постараюсь перенести с локального сервера на хостинг и затем дать ссылку на сайт.

Comment: @Natalia возьмите тему из оф каталога и ищите себе приключений на ровном месте. Поверьте, это избавить от множества проблем и позволит разобраться в ВП правильно.

Comment: Добрый день. Я уже задавала этот вопрос. У меня возникла проблема с сайтом после натяжки на WordPress. Меню "падает" под блок, в котором должно быть. И не работает адаптивность. Возможно в WordPress это все по-другому работает. Я новичок и этот макет в научных целях, но не могу понять в чем проблема. Я скину ссылку на сайт. Буду очень благодарна за помощь.
http://mysite.natalia.pw